# how to compare every line from the middle of the line with every line in a single text file using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginer in python and trying to write a script where it compares the lines a text file and print the unique ones.
Here is the input file. (I want to compare every line after the numeric value after (, ))

```
Hello world! 'I like scripting', 1: I am learning python.
Hello world! 'I like scripting',  1: I am learning perl.
Hello world! 'I like scripting', 1: I am learning both perl and python.
Hello all! 'I like scripting', 3: I am learning python.
Hello everyone! 'I like scripting', 5: I am learning perl.
Hai! 'I do not like scripting', 2: I am not learning either python or perl.
```

I am trying to print line1 (because "Hello world! 'I like scripting'" covered three possible cases so I want to print only once) and line 6 (because it is not repeated at all so I would like to print line 6)

It should print (output file should be)

```
Hello world! I like scripting 1 
Hai! I do not like scripting 2
```

I am in the intial stage in my work

```
with open ('input.txt') as input, open ('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        new_line = line.strip(', ')
```

I opened the input file and trying to strip every line after (, ) to compare every line.
I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to compare is unclear. What would be the output from your first example?

Comment: @zezollo It should be:                                                                                                              
 Hello world! I like scripting 1 
 Hai! I do not like scripting 2

Comment: OK, so lines 1 & 4 are removed because they both end with `I am learning python.` and 2 & 5 are removed too because they both end with `I am learning perl.`. So only lines 3 and 6 remain and you print their start. Alright, so, first, you probably don't want to `strip()` but to `split()` each line. There are probably more efficient ways to achieve what you want to do, but maybe you don't want to know about them yet, if you're at learning.

Comment: Another hint: do not use `input` as variable because it's a python keyword.

Comment: If you're sure the separator between the two parts of each line is always a semicolon, you could do something like `line_start, line_end = line.split(':')`

Comment: @zezollo could you please suggest me few possible ways for this solution. I would love to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use dicts and lists.
In this solution I collect all lines in a dictionary whose values are the line starts and the keys the line endinds, and if a line ending is already collected then it's a duplicate, I save it to the duplicates list. Then for each collected key, if it is not in the duplicates list, then I write it to the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

collected = dict()
duplicates = list()
with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in infile:
        line_start, line_end = line.split(':')
        if line_end in collected:
            duplicates.append(line_end)
        else:
            collected[line_end] = line_start.split(', ')[0]
    for key in collected:
        if key not in duplicates:
            output.write(f'{collected[key]}\n')
```

I guess there are "better" solutions, but couldn't find something yet as readable and clear as this one.